# dbt-Databricks row count for specific columns in different models

Tags: databricks, dbt, databricks-sql

I have three models where I'm performing custom tests on specific columns. However, I also want the COUNT(<column_name>) for each field I'm performing a test against, so I can get a count of the non-null values for each field from each of the different models.

I have created a snapshot where I've taken a count of each column for each model and UNION ALL them together like so:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(<column_name>),
  '<name_of_column>' as column_name,
FROM
  <model>
UNION ALL
  ... --repeat for rest of columns
```

However, with any new tests that are added, I would have to remember to UNION another SELECT COUNT() statement which isn't very favorable. Are there any packages or ways to structure this to get the COUNTs for these columns?